# How to reshape an array of shape (m,) to (m,1)

Tags: python-3.x, numpy-ndarray

I have an array as below.
X1=np.array([[0,0],[0,0]])

X1[:,0].shape gives me (2,).

How do I convert X1[:,0] to a shape of (2,1).

Answer (score 1):

thanks for asking. what you have is a two by two matrix, so turning one part of the array to a two dimensional array will cause an error. I think you should create a new array from the sub array and then reshape it. you can do it like this `new_x = X[:,0]
new_x.reshape(2,1)`. I hope this works